# Use Multi-threading to make looping faster - In which element is adding in list in loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, list, asynchronous

This is my code in which a list contains 2 more lists where the `WorkItem` collection contains a large number of records such as 7,000 it takes 10 minutes.

Is there any way to make it faster and in case it's deciding the `WorkItem` type if it's a bug, task, or product backlog item?

Please tell me how to make the looping faster.

It's taking 10 minutes to loop 7,000 records. Can we use threading to make it faster?

```
var workItemList = new List<WorkItemViewModel>();
for (int i = 0; i < workItemCollection.Count; i++)
{
   var workItem = workItemCollection[i];
   if (workItem.Type.Name == "Product Backlog Item")
   {
       var model = new WorkItemViewModel()
       {
           FID = (workItem.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0) ?
                 ((workItem.WorkItemLinks[0].LinkTypeEnd.Name.ToString() != "Child") ? 
                 workItem.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId : 0) : 0,

           ID = workItem.Id,
           Name = workItem.Title,
           State = workItem.State,

           priorty = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Priority"].Value),
           //   Size =(int) workItem.Fields["Size"].Value ,
           Size = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Effort"].Value),

           StoryPoints = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Story Points"].Value),
           DoneStatus = workItem.Fields["Done Status"].Value.ToString(),
           StoryOwner = workItem.Fields["Story Owner"].Value.ToString(),
           Assignedto = workItem.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),
           StoryAuthor = workItem.Fields["Story Author"].Value.ToString(),
           IterationPath = workItem.IterationPath
       };
       workItemList.Add(model);
   }
   else
   {
       switch (workItem.Type.Name)
       {
           case "Task":
               var task = new TFSTask()
               {
                   Storyid = (workItem.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0) ?
                             workItem.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId : 0,
                   ID = workItem.Id,
                   name = workItem.Title,
                   //activity = workItem.Fields["MyCompany.Activity"].Value.ToString(),
                   //start = (DateTime?)workItem.Fields["MyCompany.ActivityStart"].Value,
                   //due = (DateTime?)workItem.Fields["MyCompany.ActivityFinish"].Value,
                   status = workItem.State,
                   IterationPath = workItem.IterationPath,
                   Assignedto = workItem.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),

                   priorty = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                   effort = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["effort"].Value),
                   Completed = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Completed"].Value)

               };
               if (task.Storyid != 0)
               {
                   workItemList.Last().Tasks.Add(task);
               }

               break;
           case "Bug":
               var bug = new TFSIssue()
               {
                   Storyid = (workItem.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0) ? 
                             workItem.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId : 0,
                   ID = workItem.Id,
                   Name = workItem.Title,
                   //start = (DateTime?)workItem.Fields["MyCompany.ActivityStart"].Value,
                   //due = (DateTime?)workItem.Fields["MyCompany.ActivityFinish"].Value,
                   State = workItem.State,
                   IterationPath = workItem.IterationPath,
                   Assignedto = workItem.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),

                   priorty = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                   effort = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["effort"].Value),
                   // Completed = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Completed"].Value)
               };
               if (bug.Storyid != 0)
               {
                   workItemList.Last().Issues.Add(bug);
               }
               break;
           default:
               break;
       }
   }
}

public class WorkItemViewModel
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int ID { get; set; }

       public string State { get; set; }
       // public DateTime? due { get; set; }
       public int priorty { get; set; }
       public int Size { get; set; }
       //  public int effort { get; set; }
       public int StoryPoints { get; set; }
       public string DoneStatus { get; set; }
       public string StoryOwner { get; set; }
       public string Assignedto { get; set; }
       public string StoryAuthor { get; set; }
       public string IterationPath { get; set; }
       public int FID { get; set; }
       public List<TFSIssue> Issues { get; set; }
       public List<TFSTask> Tasks { get; set; }

       public WorkItemViewModel()  // Added a public constructor
       {
           Issues = new List<TFSIssue>();
           Tasks = new List<TFSTask>();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't with the current structure of your data. As I understand it, the relation between your backlog items and the related tasks/bugs is only explained by the relative order in the workItemCollection object. So if you were to use Parrallel.For with a ConccurentBag, you would not know to which backlog item each task/bug item should be added...

On another note, 10 minutes seems like a very long time for a simple loop of 7.000 records. Is there anything else going on that is not clear in the code? You should investigate the sub steps, to see what is taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

I have one modification to suggest but i'm not sure if it's gonna improve the performance since I can't really test it:

```
var workItemList = new List<WorkItemViewModel>();
for (int i = 0; i < workItemCollection.Count; i++)
{
   var workItem = workItemCollection[i];
   WorkItemViewModel model = null;

   switch (workItem.Type.Name)
   {
       case "Product Backlog Item":
           model = new WorkItemViewModel()
           {
               // ...
           };

           workItemList.Add(model);

       case "Task":
           var task = new TFSTask()
           {
               // ...

           };

           if (task.Storyid != 0)
           {
               model.Tasks.Add(task);
           }

           break;
       case "Bug":
           var bug = new TFSIssue()
           {
               // ...
           };

           if (bug.Storyid != 0)
           {
               model.Issues.Add(bug);
           }

           break;
       default:
           break;
   }
}
```

This way no need to call `Last()` each time you wanna add a Task or a Bug, it's better to just save the last model as a variable and make the other switch cases use that variable.

Comment: still 10.2 min (measured by stopwatch no improvement) can't it be be done be threading ?